# Coloring blank cells of a column based on value in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA macro. I am trying to create macro that colour blank cell in the column named "Cargo Received at Port of Loading" and "Full In Gate at Ocean Terminal (CY or Port)" with reference to the value in another column named "Load Type". Example if the column "Load Type" has value "BB" and "RORO" then the column "Full In Gate at Ocean Terminal (CY or Port)" with only blank cell should be coloured or highlighted with yellow. Similarly, if the column "Load Type" has a value "FCL" then the column "Cargo Received at Port of Loading" with only blank cell should be coloured or highlighted with yellow.

As highlighted in excel screen if the column "Load Type" has value "RORO" or "BB" then the column "Full In Gate at Ocean Terminal (CY or Port)" with blank cells should be in yellow colour and if the column "Load Type" has value "FCL" then the column "Cargo Received at Port of Loading" with blank cells should be in yellow colour.

Comment: Take a look at "Conditional Formatting" for Excel worksheets. You can probably achieve what you want without having to use VBA at all.

Comment: I could have done that but this sheet named "POL" is generated/created by a macro so there is a big chain of macro that generates this POL sheet so I have a doubt will condition formatting work or not and even if I put condition then value paste would be difficult because this POL sheet is ten further exported in new excel file.  Since I am new VBA macro. So I would prefer to go with a macro. @DS_London

Comment: Are there Types other than RORO, BB and FCL? If not, then you just want to colour every blank cell yellow in your sample?

Comment: @DS_London Its like if column load type has value RORO or BB then corresponding column "Full In Gate at Ocean Terminal (CY or Port)" with only blank cells should yellow colour and if column load type as value FCL then corresponding column "Cargo Received at Port of Loading" with blank cells should be a yellow colour.

Comment: There are only 3 types RORO BB and FCL in column "Load type" and there are two corresponding columns Full In Gate at Ocean Terminal (CY or Port) and Cargo Received at Port of Loading with some blank cells so based on the value present in column "Load type" i.e. RORO FCL and BB these 2 columns with blank cells should be highlighted with yellow colour so the value is RORO or BB then corresponding column Full In Gate at Ocean Terminal (CY or Port) with blank cell should be highlighted in yellow...

Comment: if type if FCL then  corresponding column Cargo Received at Port of Loading with blank cell should be highlighted in yellow @DS_London

Comment: OK ... let me ask this a different way: On the sample extract that you have shown: should any of the blank cells NOT be yellow? Could you post an example of that same extract with the colouring as you want it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED: To change colLoadType assigment

```
Option Explicit
Sub sfdf()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("frfr")

    'Assumes no blank rows in the Load Type column
    Dim colLoadType As Range, colCargo As Range, colFull As Range
    'Assumes first data is in Row 2 in the spreadsheet
    Set colLoadType = ws.Range("O2",ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count,"O").End(xlUp))

    Dim lRows As Long
    lRows = colLoadType.Rows.Count
    Set colCargo = ws.Range("S2").Resize(lRows)
    Set colFull = ws.Range("T2").Resize(lRows)

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim strType As String
    For lRow = 1 To lRows
        strType = colLoadType(lRow, 1).Value
        If (strType = "BB" Or strType = "RORO") And IsEmpty(colFull(lRow, 1)) Then
            colFull(lRow, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        ElseIf strType = "FCL" And IsEmpty(colCargo(lRow, 1)) Then
            colCargo(lRow, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    Next lRow
End Sub
```

Comment: this works but see only a few i.e. first 4 blank cells were highlighted... I have pasted the output screenshot in the question please see my edit in he question for output result. Only first 4 blank cells are coloured.. please check and help @DS_London

Comment: Pls show column headers (A,B,C,D etc), and remove the filter, so that all the cells are visible. As stated, the answer assumes the first type is in cell O2 and there are no blank rows in that column.

Comment: ,, please see the screenshot in question I have pasted again it does not highlight complete blank cells

Comment: Note there are some blank cells also in column Load Type where there value BB ROROand FCL see the output in above edits

Comment: There are bank cells in column  O

Comment: Change: Set colLoadType=ws.Range(“O2”).Resize(1000)

Comment: It’s a lousy way of doing it, but I’ve done enough for free on this ...

Comment: thanks now it's working but resize(1000) is again a range limit or what if there is data beyond then it will be a problem anyways thanks

Comment: Try this instead: Set colLoadType = ws.Range("O2",ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count,"O").End(xlUp))

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is perfect now, appreciate your help... Thanks